# Enable / Disable keys for individual users on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

Is there a way of enabling / disabling Shutdown, Switch User, Cntrl-Alt-Del, Restart etc., in all the various places for individual users, not all users, for ONE pc using Windows 7?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  The process is slightly complicated though.  Here is a tutorial:

- **[How to Allow or Prevent Users and Groups to Shut Down the Computer](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/128920-shut-down-computer-allow-prevent-users-groups.html)**

You will also need physical security measures to prevent anyone powering off the computer using power button on the case, or removing the power cord to the computer.

> Warning
>   You will need to be an administrator to open the Local Security Policy Editor.
>   The Local Security Group Policy Editor will only be available in the Windows 7 Professional, Ultimate, and Enterpise editions.
>   **You will not have the Local Security Policy Editor available in the Windows 7 Starter, Home Basic, and Home Premium editions**.

Comment: You can do pretty much anything in secpol and/or gpedit if you look hard enough.

Comment: gpedit and secpol are only available in Pro and higher versions of W7.